# How to create alias shortcut for compiling C++ code on mac

Tags: c++

I am following this article to compile my C++ code using C++17 instead of the C++98 in mac. Article - [link](https://dev.to/ayushpattnaik/running-c-17-on-mac-m1-47cp)

It works perfectly but the only problem is that the command to compile is very long and hard to remember for future use so I thought of creating an alias for it. I followed this article for that - [link](https://mattmazur.com/2012/01/27/how-to-add-terminal-aliases-in-mac-os-x-lion/)

I added the alias command as `alias cpp='c++ --std=gnu++17'` .

Then while compilation I ran the command as `cpp signals.cpp`

This gave the error that

`signals.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found`

What am I doing wrong? Can I not use alias command with a filename like above? What is the way to do it?

Comment: From *where* did you run the command `cpp`? In the same environment that has the alias? Some other environment?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude in the same environment did not use any virtual environment anywhere just changed directory

Comment: looks like an issue in the code line 1... are you including the iostream library correctly?

Comment: When you say "environment" do you mean the same *terminal* and same *shell*? What are the *exact* commands you use? Please **[edit]** your question to include the commands, from the alias to the compilation, and then show the exact output. And please copy-paste it all as *text*.